# ORACLE SQL Query records where timeinterval with previous record is less then eg 1 minute

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, lag, lead

From **input table** query all records where time-difference is less or equal then **1 minute**.

[image: Input table]

**Required Output**

[image: Output]

[>>>>>sqlfiddle <<<<<](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5fc1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select *
from (select a.*,
             lag(sdt) over (partition by id order by sdt) as prevsdt,
             lead(sdt) over (partition by id order by sdt) as nextsdt
      from table_a a
     ) a
where sdt - prevsdt <= 1/(24*60) or
      nextsdt - sdt <= 1/(24*60);
```

It produces the desired output on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5fc1/62).

Comment: +1 Beat me. Using `LAG` and `LEAD` seems to be the way to go here.

Comment: Just a nitpick: I guess you don't really need the inner query, you could use the analytic functions directly on the first `SELECT`.

Comment: @rsenna You can't use analytic functions in the WHERE.